# output specific layers of json file with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json file with the following structure:

```
    {
    "Branch 1": {
        "name": "Branch 1 Name",
        "image": "branch1.jpg",
        "categories": {
            "category 1": {
                "name": "Category 1 Name",
                "image": "Category1.jpg",
                "products":{
                    "product1":{
                        "id": "245748",
                        "name": "product 4",
                        "description": "description 1"
                    },
                    "product2":{
                        "id": "245738",
                        "name": "product 5",
                        "description": "description 2"
                    },
                    "product3":{
                        "id": "123738",
                        "name": "product 6",
                        "description": "description 3"
                    }
                }
            },
            "category 2": {
                "name": "Category 2 Name",
                "image": "Category2.jpg",
                "products":{
                    "product1":{
                        "id": "444738",
                        "name": "product 4",
                        "description": "description 1"
                    },
                    "product2":{
                        "id": "554738",
                        "name": "product 5",
                        "description": "description 2"
                    },
                    "product3":{
                        "id": "432738",
                        "name": "product 6",
                        "description": "description 3"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Branch 2": {
        "name": "Branch 2 Name",
        "image": "branch2.jpg",
        "categories": {
            "category 1": {
                "name": "Category 1 Name",
                "image": "Category1.jpg",
                "subCategories": {
                    "subCategory 1": {
                        "name": "subCategory 1 Name",
                        "image": "subCategory1.jpg",
                        "products":{
                            "product1":{
                                "id": "654433",
                                "name": "product 4",
                                "description": "description 1"
                            },
                            "product2":{
                                "id": "432123",
                                "name": "product 5",
                                "description": "description 2"
                            },
                            "product3":{
                                "id": "776534",
                                "name": "product 6",
                                "description": "description 3"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "subCategory 2": {
                        "name": "subCategory 2 Name",
                        "image": "subCategory2.jpg",
                        "products":{
                            "product1":{
                                "id": "446534",
                                "name": "product 4",
                                "description": "description 1"
                            },
                            "product2":{
                                "id": "116534",
                                "name": "product 5",
                                "description": "description 2"
                            },
                            "product3":{
                                "id": "772234",
                                "name": "product 6",
                                "description": "description 3"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "category 2": {
                "name": "Category 2 Name",
                "image": "Category2.jpg",
                "subCategories": {
                    "subCategory 1": {
                        "name": "subCategory 1 Name",
                        "image": "subCategory1.jpg",
                        "products":{
                            "product1":{
                                "id": "321234",
                                "name": "product 4",
                                "description": "description 1"
                            },
                            "product2":{
                                "id": "433534",
                                "name": "product 5",
                                "description": "description 2"
                            },
                            "product3":{
                                "id": "123434",
                                "name": "product 6",
                                "description": "description 3"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "subCategory 2": {
                        "name": "subCategory 2 Name",
                        "image": "subCategory2.jpg",
                        "products":{
                            "product1":{
                                "id": "887663",
                                "name": "product 4",
                                "description": "description 1"
                            },
                            "product2":{
                                "id": "879767",
                                "name": "product 5",
                                "description": "description 2"
                            },
                            "product3":{
                                "id": "987678",
                                "name": "product 6",
                                "description": "description 3"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I output a specific layer of this json file. I have one page where I need only the branches, and another page where I only need the Categorys of a branch. And then one page deeper, I just need the subcategorys of a category or branch. And at the deepest page i just need the products of a category.

Is there an easy way to parse this json file and access it's "layers" as needed?

Answer (score 0):

```
// parse json to object
var obj = JSON.parse(yourJSON);
// deep copy the part of the object that you need
var categories = jQuery.extend({}, obj.categories);
// make a json out of it, if that's what you need
var categoriesJSON = JSON.stringify(categories);
```

The last step is if you actually need it as JSON, but I suppose that's not the case, you can use `categories` object on your page.